# Execute stored procedure in SQL Server with parameters from Excel sheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I have a requirement but I am little confused on which method to approach.

**Requirement**: there is a stored procedure that is created in SQL Server which performs some updates to a table.

Now I have an Excel sheet with some object ID's filled in `Sheet1`. I need to pass these object IDs to the procedure in SQL Server and it will update the records in the table based on this object ID's. Once these updates are over, the refreshed table is then displayed in another sheet.

I was thinking of writing a macro with a button in the first sheet which executes the stored procedure and returns the refreshed table. Or is there any alternate approach available ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Using a VBA macro is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks David for your comment. When googled, I found multiple answers suggesting to go for Power Query.  I wasn't sure whether power query is the best way to solve this.

Comment: You should not use Power Query for a stored procedure that modifies data.  That's just for reporting.

Comment: (Call Stored Procedure from Excel and show results - YouTube) Whatch this video in yotube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-FkJoGMpCE